# angular with database directily without using php/java

Tags: angularjs

Is there any way to connect angular based application  to database directly using some non php / java application , i am hosting a website want this javascript based only.

right now i am using like this example from w3schoole , want pure query based plugin

```
  app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers_sql.aspx")
.success(function (response) {$scope.names = response.records;});
```

});

Comment: your angular application can technically send http requests to databases that hold http endpoints and query them for data directly. you should check out if your db supports this and if so, how to set this up.

Answer (score 0):

Most NoSql databases have some form of REST API that allow you to perform CRUD operations.

I have used [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/) recently  which also has a nice UI to view the data and the sandbox version is free to use.